# JAXB binding error, "Content must match...?"

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, schema, yql

I have written a  .xsd schema (below) for use with Yahoo's YQL [yahoo.finance.quote table](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22Goog%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys)
.  But when I use xjc to bind the schema I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'query' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: attribute.
  line 35 of file:
```

Here is the shema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng">
  <xsd:element name="query">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="results" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="quote" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="AverageDailyVolume" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Change" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element name="DaysLow" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element name="DaysHigh" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element name="YearLow" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element name="YearHigh" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element name="MarketCapitalization" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
                    <xsd:element name="LastTradePriceOnly" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element name="DaysRange" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Name" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Symbol" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Volume" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="StockExchange" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:attribute name="symbol" type="xsd:normalizedString" use="required"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="count" type="xsd:int" use="required"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="created" type="xsd:normalizedString" use="required"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="lang" type="xsd:normalizedString" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Could anyone please explain to me what the error means specifically and/or correct it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine the problem is the 3 attributes (count,created,lang) that you duplicated outside the "complexType" definition (at the bottom of the file).

Comment: Oops should have used copy-paste, sorry the actual file only contained those attributes once.  I will fix that in my question.